# Do you know of any mathematical theorem whose proof relies on the use of the principle of explosion (ECQ)?

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic, philosophy-of-logic

Ex contradictione (sequitur) quodlibet (ECQ) is almost universally recognised in mathematical logic as a valid inference.

In symbolic logic, this inference is usually expressed in the following way:

> A, ¬A ⊢ B.

This is usually referred to today as "the principle of explosion":

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion

My question is a simple one: Is there any mathematical theorem whose proof relies on the use of ECQ?

If any, what are these theorems?

Comment: You already posted the [exact same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3209477/any-consequence-for-mathematics-of-falsifying-the-principle-of-explosion) on Mathematics SE. Please do not post the same question across multiple sites.

Comment: There are logics that do not include the principle of explosion, for example, relevance logics and paraconsistent logics. The consequence is: they do not explode. What other consequences were you expecting?

Comment: I changed "falsifying" to "rejecting". If I misstated your intention please roll this back.

Comment: @FrankHubeny Well, not quite. I'm not sure what "rejecting" would mean in this instance. By "falsifying", I meant that someone might prove that there isn't any "explosion" to begin with: A ∧ ¬A ⊬ B.

Comment: How do you plan to *prove* A ∧ ¬A ⊬ B?

Comment: @FrankHubeny LOL. I don't plan anything of the sort. I will wait till somebody smarter does it. Meanwhile, I would like to understand whether proving it would have any substantial impact on mathematical results. Don't tell me you think it can't possibly be proved false?

Comment: It can't be proven in classical logic. This can be shown using a truth table. Put *~((A&&~A)=>B)* in this truth table tool to see: http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool/ However, one can reject the law of non-contradiction (explosion) and see what logics one can construct. Then you would have a kind of paraconsistent logic. The consequences are having a weaker (though perhaps more expressive) logic. This is not "no consequence at all".

Comment: It is rather plain that natural (or even much of scientific) reasoning does not validate explosion. The consequence is that it is not exhausted by mathematics and formal theories. Not very deep or exciting, I am afraid.

Comment: @FrankHubeny Yes, I know the stuff. Yet, any logical proof is based on assumptions and usually we don't even realise we start by making assumptions because there are implicit, otherwise they are called axioms, hypotheses, premises etc. I haven't found any justification of mathematical classical logic as being correct, so I have to remain open to the idea that it's based on some assumption that's just wrong. It would be irrational not to. And that no one knows of any such wrong assumption doesn't prove there isn't any.

Comment: @Conifold Whether mathematical logic tallies with human reasoning is a side issue here, although the fact that it doesn't certainly suggests we should be able find a better theory of logic. The question is whether the principle of explosion has any consequence, or import, in mathematics.

Comment: "Better" depends on the purpose. Classical logic works pretty well in mathematics and mathematized sciences. Paraconsistent and epistemic logics already provide the "better" for other purposes, including semantics of natural reasoning. There is even a well developed [inconsistent mathematics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-inconsistent/) as well.

Comment: @Conifold Thanks for the link, I wasn't aware of that particular detour. I see all these quirky alternative theories of mathematics and logic as symptoms. These people are doing what Russell and his successors did, i.e. bypass around what you don't understand as if it was a localised failure of reality. The mathematical mindset apparently let you get away with it. Still, if it works well... How would you know your "logic" really works well? What's the criterion? That it seems to work well?

Comment: I have another explanation. They are symptoms that your dream about something that does the job of a (magic) bullet and a (golden) hammer, at the same time, is naive. Logic is our representational tool, not a piece of reality to be mirrored, and you do not see understanding because you misunderstand what you are looking at. As with any tool, the criterion is whether it gets the job done. The jobs are many, some for bullets and some for hammers, but none for magic. For example, prediction and engineering design made sizable advances since the 17th, and especially 19-th, centuries.

Comment: @Conifold Precisely. So, tell me exactly what is the job actually done in mathematics by the valid inference A ∧ ¬A ⊢ B? Where is it ever being put to use? What important theorems have been proved using it? Simple question, simple answer please.

Comment: It is a price to pay for using the material implication. And that is the basis of most advanced math developed since 19th century because it allows to reason without domain restrictions and transfer theorems across theories. Starting with fixed calculus imported into functional analysis and differential geometry.

Comment: @Conifold No straight answer then. Still, at least I can always infer all by myself that your answer is implicit admission that A ∧ ¬A ⊢ B has never ever been used by any proper mathematician to prove anything...

Comment: Why bother inferring? This is your article of faith anyway. But when you are in a more inquisitive mood I advise exploring the relations between the material implication, explosion and reductio, as well as the difference between use and mention. There is a reason why dialetheists had so much trouble eliminating explosion, and why it didn't take. Hint: you must give up either [the disjunction introduction or the disjunctive syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraconsistent_logic#Tradeoffs), and (not only) mathematicians just wouldn't stop using those.

Comment: @Conifold OK, thanks for the advice. I rephrased so that people are not confused as to what is the question exactly...

Comment: Your rephrasing does not eliminate your own confusion. People do not name  explosion, it appears as a combination of proof by cases (disjunction introduction) with reductios of all but one (disjunctive syllogism), which is ubiquitous since Euclid, see e.g. [I.6](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI6.html). Is a rose only rose when it is so named?

Comment: Consider the theorem that there are infinitely many primes. One usually shows this by indirect proof (reductio ad absurdum). Assume there is a largest prime, N. Multiply all the primes and add 1. That number is either prime or contains a prime larger than N. Hence one rejects that N is the largest prime. One can look at this as a proof by cases as @Conifold suggests. Either there is a largest prime or there isn't. Reach a contradiction when considering the case there is a largest prime. Invoke explosion to give you anything you want.for that case, choose there is no largest prime.

Comment: It seem to me that the question is not being addressed. I haven't come across any use of 'explosion' being useful in mathematics, and suspect it represents the end of mathematics, but I'm not a mathematician. I'd agree with the OP that in philosophy paraconsistent logics are an underhand dodge to avoid problems and disguise incomprehension, not a solution for anything.      . . .

Comment: @PeterJ You also do not come across absorption or Peirce's law, or other tautologies of classical logic, infinitely many of them, most unnamed. Should we conclude that mathematicians do not rely on classical logic? Or that those can be somehow split off from what they do use by name? Because that seems to be the idea behind the OP's question, which is why it is impossible to address.

Comment: @Conifold Thank you to let me judge for myself whether "explosion" might be implicit in reduction. My question has been rephrased. It is easy to understand and easy to answer. Yet, you still don't give the answer. I can only infer you can't bring yourself to do it. Do I use toilet paper myself? Yes I do. See, it's easy. Yes or no. But no, you can't. More shameful that using toilet paper? That has to be fascinating. Your reply to Peter is also a fudge. Anyway, I guess we can let it at that. In a way, this has to be more informative than any yes or no answer. We're doing Freudian analysis here.

Comment: @FrankHubeny Thanks, too, for your informative reply.

Comment: The analogy to toilet paper just shows that you do not fully understand what you are asking. Toilet paper is an isolated object, it is indeed easy to tell when an individual piece was "used" or not. Classical logic is a theoretical system, it makes little sense to ask if some piece of it, taken in isolation, has been "relied on". As a result, your "whose proof relies on" is equivocal, and the "fudges" simply point out your mistake. Both readings of it were already answered, but the answer to one (trivial) reading does little to answer the other (substantive) one.

Comment: I think we're running short on things to say. If not a yes or a no, elaboration might have been possible. But no, all you can do is criticise the question, and then not much more than a vague and nondescript criticism. I still don't have my answer, I still don't know why, and I don't know where the problem might be exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the question:

> Given that the principle only affects validity, not soundness, I would expect no consequence at all. Is that correct?

To reject the [law of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion) means rejecting the law of contradiction. Paraconsistent logics attempt ["to deal with contradictions in a discriminating way"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraconsistent_logic#Definition). They want ["to formalize inconsistent but non-trivial theories"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraconsistent_logic#Definition). In classical logic a single inconsistency in a theory implies that the theory is trivial since every sentence of the theory is a theorem.

However, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraconsistent_logic#Paraconsistent_logics_and_classical_logic) notes that there are consequences when comparing these logics with classical logic:

> Paraconsistent logics are propositionally weaker than classical logic; that is, they deem fewer propositional inferences valid. The point is that a paraconsistent logic can never be a propositional extension of classical logic, that is, propositionally validate everything that classical logic does. In some sense, then, paraconsistent logic is more conservative or cautious than classical logic.

The consequences of rejecting explosion (and hence non-contradiction) result in a logic that is weaker than classical logic although it may be more expressive.

---

Here is the question after the revision:

> Do you know of any mathematical theorem whose proof relies on the use of the principle of explosion (ECQ)?

---

One could look at theorems that rely on indirect proof (reductio ad absudrum) or which could be viewed as cases that one eliminates. The indirect proof makes an assumption, reaches a contradiction and then rejects the assumption. This can be viewed as a proof by cases using the principle of bivalence: Either the assumption is true or its negation is true.

Here is an example.  Prove that there are infinitely many primes.

For the indirect proof approach, assume there are finitely many primes and let N be the largest prime. Multiply all of the finitely many primes together and add 1 to it. That number is either prime or it contains a prime divisor larger than N. That contradicts the assumption that N is the largest prime and so the assumption is rejected.

To see this as a proof by cases where explosion is used claim that either there is a largest prime or there is not a largest prime. Consider the case when there is a largest prime. Use the method above to reach a contradiction. Use explosion to get any result one wants. Choose the result that there is no largest prime. Now in both cases one gets the same result. Use disjunction elimination to conclude there is no largest prime.

---

Wikipedia contributors. (2019, April 6). Paraconsistent logic. In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Retrieved 15:44, May 1, 2019, from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Paraconsistent_logic&oldid=891268995